# I can't make a nether portal in MCPE 12.1

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In my single-player, superflat world, I went a few blocks away from spawn, but when I made the 5x4 standard portal and set fire, I couldn't go to the nether, although I had in previous worlds.

Comment: Does the portal appear (The purple effect)? What happens when you try to go through it?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, looks like your nether portal is not big enough.

> A nether portal is built as a frame of obsidian (4×5 minimum, 23×23 maximum).
> https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_portal

You need 4 blocks width, 5 blocks tall of obsidian. The four edges are actually not required. And you need to light it up with fire (flint and steel)

If you get it right, you should have a nether portal with purple effect and some sound effect.

Comment: I tried as many different shapes as I could, and the portal would not light, nor would it show the particles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be on infinite, ok